# Restore WebView position to same content on orientation change (Android)

Tags: android, android-webview, android-orientation

I am facing an issue with `WebView` content scroll position and here it is: I am scolling down the page to some extent in portrait mode and when I change orientation to landscape the scroll moves up or down. It doesnt show the exact content which is there in portrait mode. I did try doing changes in Manifest file as `configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` but no luck. I did override `onConfigurationChanged()` but that did not work. I implemented the accepted answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855715/maintain-webview-content-scroll-position-on-orientation-change) but of no use. Can somebody suggest what has to be done and why doesn't it work? This is for Google Nexus Tab and the min required SDK version is 14.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 6):

I remember facing the same problem with my app. If I'm not mistaken, the solution suggested by Phil doesn't work (on some versions of Android?).

I'm using the following approach now:

1. in onSaveInstanceState save the current scroll position of the WebView: `outState.putInt(EXTRA_SCROLL_POSITION, webView.getScrollY());`
2. in onCreate, get the last scroll-position from the savedInstanceState and set a custom WebViewClient:

   ```
   setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

       @Override
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           super.onPageFinished(view, url);

           if (!scrolled) {
               postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       scrollBy(0, scroll);
                   }
               }, 250);

               scrolled = true;
           }
       }
   });
   ```

This is ugly as hell, but it kinda works for me (this doesn't account for the current zoom-level, etc). There's lot about that code you could improve, but it basically does the trick.

Comment: My activity when changing orientation it doesnt get recreated. How do I make use of onSaveInstanceState, which gets called only when it looses focus to another app. Since my activity is not recreated so I cant make use of onRestoreInstanceState also. @TomTasche

Comment: Oh, I see. You could use `onConfigurationChanged` instead of onRestoreInstanceState, but I have no idea what you could replace onSaveInstanceState with. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

View classes have an `onSaveInstanceState()` method that returns a `Parcelable`, and an `onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)` method to restore the state. If I recall correctly, the saved state includes scroll position. All you need to do is save the Parcelable you get from a call to the WebView's `onSaveInstanceState()` in your fragment's `onSaveInstanceState` method:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById( ... );
    savedState.putParcelable("myKey", webView.onSaveInstanceState());

}
```

Then in your `onCreateView` method you restore that state, if available:

```
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, 
    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById( ... );
        Parcelable savedState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("myKey");
        if (savedState != null) {
           webView.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState);
        }
    }

    ....

}
```

Comment: Please take a look at comment of Tom Tasche's answer.

Comment: If you're not using fragments then no, this won't work. If this is a big enough problem for you it might be worth spending a couple of hours trying a fragment-based version (you should be moving to fragments inside activities anyway, and the support library will provide backwards compatibility).

Comment: I just tried this but the line `savedState.putParcelable("myKey", webView.onSaveInstanceState());` gives me the error `onSaveInstanceState() has protected access in android.view.View`

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of **onSaveInstanceState** to save the **state of scrollview** and **restore in  onRestoreInstanceState** method.**Have u used Scrollview thr xml**?if **yes** then **get reference** to that view and when **activity restore** then **set position of scrollview** to the saved state.Hope this Helps.

Comment: Please look at my comment for TomTasche answer