# How to save scroll position of webview in android

Tags: java, android, android-webview

In my application, I use `WebView` for show **HTML** books.
I want when read this book store **position of content** and when close this `WebView` save this **position** and when again goto this book, not show the top of content, show **continue** of this **position**.

How can I make it?

Comment: Not a perfect one but This might help you [save-scroll-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855715/maintain-webview-content-scroll-position-on-orientation-change)

Comment: hi i have some code to save webview position if you want then reopen your question.

Comment: @MukeshWondersoft, yes my friend, can you help me?

Comment: yes, i have some code that save webview state to bytesArray and then restore when you start again. but its depend on website that you load into webview.

Comment: @MukeshWondersoft can you send to me code?

Comment: yes but can't answer to this question because you closed it. were can i send code?